# Python の while list1 and list2 が理解できない

Tags: python

leetcodeでソートされている連結リストをマージする問題です。
list1 とlist2 が与えられている連結リストです。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、while list1 and list2:のところはどのような意味なのでしょうか。
list1とlist2がブール値ということですか？

```
class Solution:
def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    cur = dummy = ListNode()
    while list1 and list2:               
        if list1.val < list2.val:
            cur.next = list1
            list1, cur = list1.next, list1
        else:
            cur.next = list2
            list2, cur = list2.next, list2
            
    if list1 or list2:
        cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
        
    return dummy.next
```

Answer (score 1):

下記にあるように
オブジェクトにより `False` と判定されるものがあります

質問の場合, `ListNode()` の定義によるけど linked listが続いてなければ Falseと判断するようになっているものと思われます

docs.python.org [組み込み型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html) より

> **真理値判定**
> どのようなオブジェクトでも真理値として判定でき、`if` や `while` の条件あるいは以下のブール演算の被演算子として使えます。
> オブジェクトは、デフォルトでは真と判定されます。ただしそのクラスが `__bool__()` メソッドを定義していて、それが `False` を返す場合、または `__len__()` メソッドを定義していて、それが `0` を返す場合は偽と判定されます。主な組み込みオブジェクトで偽と判定されるものを次に示します:
>
> - 偽であると定義されている定数: `None` と `False`
> - 数値型におけるゼロ: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - 空のシーケンスまたはコレクション: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

> **ブール演算 --- `and`, `or`, `not`**
> 以下にブール演算を、優先順位が低い順に示します:
>
> | 演算 | 結果 | 注釈 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `x or y` | x が偽なら y, そうでなければ x |  |
> | `x and y` | x が偽なら x, そうでなければ y |  |
> | `not x` | x が偽なら True, そうでなければ False |  |

Answer (score 0):

> list1とlist2がブール値ということですか？

bool 型に cast して(`__bool__()`メソッド, もしくは `__len__()` メソッドの実行結果から)判定しています。

```py
>>> bool([]) # empty list
False
>>> bool([1])
True
>>> bool([[]]) # list of empty list
True
>>> bool([None]) # list of None
True
```

つまり、要素がある場合は `True`, ない場合は `False` になります。